# How do I concatenate 2 dictionaries which have the same keys, while retaining all the values?

Tags: python, dictionary, concatenation

Let's say I have

`d1 = { k1:v1, k2:v2, k3:v3}`

and

`d2 = { k1:v4, k2:v5, k3:v6}`

How can I merge these two dictionaries in such a way that

`d = { k1:v1, k2:v2, k3:v3, k4:v4, k5:v5, k6:v6}`?

Currently I'm using this piece of code which is brute force and not that efficient when it comes to larger dictionaries:

```
d = {}
d1 = { '1':v1, '2':v2, '3':v3}
d2 = { '1':v4, '2':v5, '3':v6}

i = len(d1)
for k in d2.keys():
    d[str(i)] = d2[k]
    i += 1
```

I am an amateur when it comes to coding so can someone please help me out?

Comment: In your for loop, you are referring to an object ```d```, this does not exist. If you mean ```d1``` or ```d2```, please update your code snippet. Additionally, you say you want to retain all values. How would you want that? Should values belonging to the same key be grouped in a list?

Comment: right, i forgot to include the d that is a dictionary that is created before this whole piece of code. I figured people would understand so I didn't bother adding but I guess it was needed so I hope your doubt is clarified :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension. If you're going to systematically assign new keys, you can combine the list of values from the two dictionaries and let `enumerate()` generate sequential keys for you:

```
d1 = { '1':"v1", '2':"v2", '3':"v3"}
d2 = { '1':"v4", '2':"v5", '3':"v6"}

d = { str(i):v for i,v in enumerate((*d1.values(),*d2.values()),1) }

print(d)                          
{'1': 'v1', '2': 'v2', '3': 'v3', '4': 'v4', '5': 'v5', '6': 'v6'}
```

Comment: thank you very much! this actually helps my problem statement since all i need is each value to just have a different key and doesn't have to be specific.